# ListView layout problem

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

I am trying to preview an exercise log where it shows all the exercises that the user perform in a day along with the duration and the burned calories, at the end there will be the total calories burned in that day.
when I first tried to do this, I build a layout with 10 rows each has 3 text views that represent the exercise name, duration and the burned calories. but it was impractical, since the user entries will differ from day to day. So I came up with this solution which I am not sure if it is some thing I can do in android or not.
please take a look, and tell me what's wrong  *excuse me for the long introduction*

**the layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TableLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="0">
        <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:text="Activity" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content">
            </TextView>
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:text="Duration" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TextView>
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:text="Burned" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TextView>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <ListView android:id="@+id/lstAct" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ListView>
        <ListView android:id="@+id/lstDur" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ListView>
        <ListView android:id="@+id/lstbrn" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ListView>         
        </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">           
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" Total Burned Calories">
        </TextView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/Totbrn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" Kcal">
        </TextView>
    </TableRow> 
        <Button android:id="@+id/addExcBtn" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:text="Add another exercise" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>           
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**This is the class code:**

```
public class ExerciseDiary extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private DataBaseHelper helper;
private ListView l1;
private ListView l2;
private ListView l3;
static String[] activity;
static Integer[] duration;
static Integer[] burned;

@Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.test);
      helper = new DataBaseHelper(this);      
      l1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstAct);
      l2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstDur);
      l3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstbrn);
      fillArray();
      l1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.items,activity));
      l2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, R.layout.items,duration));
      l3.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, R.layout.items,burned));
          View AddButton = findViewById(R.id.addExcBtn);
      AddButton.setOnClickListener(this);                 
   }
public void onClick(View v){
       switch (v.getId()) {     
            case R.id.addExcBtn:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Exercise.class));
            break;                              
       }
   }
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity_DietTracker.class));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}   
public void fillArray(){
    GregorianCalendar toDay = new GregorianCalendar();
    String today = AllCmnMtd.getDate(toDay);
    activity = new String[100];
    duration = new Integer[100];
    burned = new Integer[100];
    int i = 0;
      helper.openDataBase();          
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("Select * from ExerciseLog where EDate = '" + today + "'", null);
    if(c!=null){
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                activity[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Exercise"));
                duration[i] = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Duration"));
                burned[i] = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Burned"));
                i++;
            }while(c.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    helper.close();
}
}
```

**and these are the errors:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource (ArrayAdapter.java:351)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1251)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1117)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1030)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7115)
at android.widget.TableRow.measureChildBeforeLayout(TableRow.java:221)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal (LinearLayout.java:619)
at android.widget.TableRow.onMeasure(TableRow.java:112)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7115)
```

and about 25 others.

if anyone has any information about that or if there is another way to do it,please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: I really have no clue what you are trying there but I can tell you that you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Going to need some code around the view being inflated for a NullPointer.

Comment: Start by explaining what you want to do.. Then we will all know what you're trying to accomplish. Also post the code for the ArrayAdapter that is throwing the NullPOinter

Answer (score 0):

The XML is just a part of the problem. In main class you have to declare an instance of the view as member data:
private ListView mConversationView;

Then in your onCreate you have to initialize the pointer.
 mConversationView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.in);

If you don't to the latter, you will get the null pointers your seeing.